# IntelliJ blue line highlight showing

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

While working with IntelliJ I used a shortcut wrongly and now I have a dark blue highlited line, which means nothing.

It is some sort of marker highlighting.

How can I get rid of it? See image.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't go away with Ctrl+Z :)

Comment: Looks like a selected line, did you click somewhere? You probably did hit a shortcut for "Select line at caret"

Comment: Probably you've enable highlighting of the line. Check Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Backgroung, it should be unchecked.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you were stepping through the code while using the debugger, current execution point line would be highlighted in a similar way (though, a different color is used by default):

[image: execution point]

Stopping the debugger should remove the line.

Comment: As it looks it was really the debugger, I haven't noticed it completely. Thank you.

Comment: When I see answers like this I immediately face-palm because of my stupidity. Thank you.